# Product Combination of variables by loop in R with data table

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have an initial table in R including 7 variables as shown below:

```
library(data.table)
Data<-data.frame(
  ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  CP1 =c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0),
  CP2 =c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
  CP3 =c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
  PR1 =c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  PR2=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  PR3=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
  
  )
Data

> Data
   ID CP1 CP2 CP3 PR1 PR2 PR3
1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
3   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
4   2   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   2   0   0   0   0   0   1
6   2   0   1   0   0   0   0
7   3   1   0   0   0   0   0
8   3   0   1   0   0   0   0
9   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  4   1   0   0   0   0   0
11  4   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  4   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

I want to create all the product combination of CP1, CP2 and CP3 with the PR1, PR2 and PR3 variables, with the following names CP1_PR1, CP1_PR2, CP1_PR3, CP2_PR1, CP2_PR2, CP2_PR3, CP3_PR1, CP3_PR2 and CP3_PR3.

***But I want to use a condition for doing this product. When both CP and PR variable are equal to 1 I want to create the CP_PR variable which will be equal to 1 and also to make zero the initial CP variable.***

I make a vector with the names of the CP variables and a vector of the PR variables:

```
ListCP<-colnames(Data)[2:4]
ListPr<-colnames(Data)[5:7]
```

And then I use a double for loop in order to create the needed product combination Variables which correct creates the combinations I want:

```
for (i in ListPr) {
  
  for (j in ListCP) {
    
    Data<-Data[,paste0(j,"_",i) := ifelse(get(i)==1 & get(j)==1,1,0)]

    
  }
  
}

> Data
> Data
    ID CP1 CP2 CP3 Pr1 Pr2 Pr3 CP1_Pr1 CP2_Pr1 CP3_Pr1 CP1_Pr2 CP2_Pr2 CP3_Pr2 CP1_Pr3 CP2_Pr3 CP3_Pr3
 1:  1   1   0   0   1   0   0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 2:  1   0   1   0   1   0   0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 3:  1   0   1   0   0   1   0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
 4:  2   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 5:  2   0   0   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 6:  2   0   1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 7:  3   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 8:  3   0   1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 9:  3   0   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
10:  4   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
11:  4   0   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
12:  4   0   0   1   0   0   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
```

Then when I am trying to make zero the initial CP vars in case that I said above I am getting an error.

```
> for (i in ListCP) {
+   
+   for (j in ListPr) {
+     
+     Data<-Data[paste0(j,"_",i)==1,.(j) := 0]
+     
+     
+   }
+   
+ }
Error in `[.data.table`(Data, paste0(j, "_", i) == 1, `:=`(.(j), 0)) : 
  LHS of := must be a symbol, or an atomic vector (column names or positions).
```

My question here is if I can combine both double for loops into one without getting an error.
Also, because my dataset is bigger, any other faster implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses the variables `.SD` and its accompanying `.SDcols` and only one `for` loop is needed. This seems to be a more natural way of doing it.

```r
library(data.table)

Data<-data.frame(
  ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  CP1 =c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0),
  CP2 =c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
  CP3 =c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
  PR1 =c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  PR2=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  PR3=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
)
Data2 <- as.data.table(Data)
Data <- as.data.table(Data)
                                              
ListCP<-colnames(Data)[2:4]
ListPr<-colnames(Data)[5:7]

for (i in ListPr) {
  for (j in ListCP) {
    Data<-Data[,paste0(j,"_",i) := ifelse(get(i)==1 & get(j)==1,1,0)]
  }
}

for(j in ListPr) {
  new_cols <- paste0(ListCP, "_", j)
  j_val <- Data2[[j]]
  Data2[, (new_cols) := lapply(.SD, \(i) +(i & j_val)), .SDcols = ListCP]
}

all.equal(Data, Data2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

For the new question, try the following.
It must be run in a separate loop, first use the original values of the `CP` variables as above and only afterward change to 0 if the new columns are 1.

```
for(j in ListPr) {
  new_cols <- paste0(ListCP, "_", j)
  Data2[, (ListCP) := ifelse(.SD == 1, 0L, .SD), .SDcols = ListCP, by = new_cols]
}
```

Comment: Hi Rui, and thank you for you answer. I tried to run it and i got an error                                 
 > for(j in ListPr) {
+   new_cols <- paste0(ListCP, "_", j)
+   j_val <- Data2[[j]]
+   Data2[, (new_cols) := lapply(.SD, \(i) +(i & j_val)), .SDcols = ListCP]
Error: unexpected input in:
"  j_val <- Data2[[j]]
  Data2[, (new_cols) := lapply(.SD, \"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> 
> all.equal(Data, Data2)
[1] "Different number of columns" "Different column names"                                                               Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Didie If your version of R is prior to 4.1, instead of `\(i)` try `function(i)`. I have just reran the code as posted and it worked. The new lambda `\(i)` was introduced in R 4.1.0.

Comment: Thank you again. I replace \(i) with function(i) as you said and it works like mine. Also, I would like when the Combination Variable is equal 1 (which mean than both CP and PR variable are 1) to put Zero value to CP variables. That I tried to use 2 double for loops. Do you have any suggestion ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Didie if CP1 = 1, PR1=1 and PR2 = 0, then it is clear that CP1_PR1 = 1 and CP1_PR2=0, but in this case should CP1 be changed to 0 (because the product of cp1 and pr1 is 1), or should it stay as 1 (because the product of cp1 and pr2 is 0)?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you again for your quick response. From the moment that the interaction product is equal to 1 then the CP variable should be changed to 0. For example in the first row of the table I would like CP1 to be equal to 0, Pr1 equal to 1 and CP1_Pr1 also equal to 1. Thank you again !!!

Comment: @Didie See if the edit is what you want.

Comment: @RuiBarradas It seems to work! Thank you so much! I am grateful for your help!

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry for coming back. But I found out some cases in my real data set that it does not work. I will try to explain you again with an example about what I try to do: Data[CP1_PR1==1 | CP1_PR2==1 | CP1_PR3==1, CP1:=0] !!! Also, I would like to ask you what is the mean j_val <- Data2[[j]] in the second loop ? Thank you again.

Comment: @Didie  `Data2` comes from the first loop and is not needed, will edit.

Comment: @RuiBarradas You are right. Was my mistake I mean Data2. But I still take not expected results for some rows. I right down all the combinations Data2[CP1_PR1==1 | CP1_PR2==1 | CP1_PR3==1, CP1:=0] Data2[CP2_PR1==1 | CP2_PR2==1 | CP2_PR3==1, CP2:=0] Data2[CP3_PR1==1 | CP3_PR2==1 | CP3_PR3==1, CP3:=0] and it works. Can I do it within for loop?

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

- based on clarification from OP, re when CP values should be updated:

```
df =  melt(Data[, id:=.I], id="id",measure =patterns("CP", "PR"), value.name = c("CP", "PR"))

prods = list()
for( i in unique(df$variable)) {
  for(j in unique(df$variable)) {
    prod = merge(df[variable==i], df[variable==j], by="id")[,`:=`(p=CP.x*PR.y)]
    df <- df[prod[, .(id,p)], CP:=fifelse(p==1 & variable==i, 0, CP), on="id"]
    prods = c(prods,list(setnames(prod[,.(p)],new=paste0("CP",i,"_PR",j))))
  }
}

cbind(
  Data[, .(ID)],
  dcast(df, id~variable, value.var=c("CP","PR"), sep=""),
  do.call(cbind, prods)
)[,id:=NULL][]
```

Output:

```
    ID CP1 CP2 CP3 PR1 PR2 PR3 CP1_PR1 CP1_PR2 CP1_PR3 CP2_PR1 CP2_PR2 CP2_PR3 CP3_PR1 CP3_PR2 CP3_PR3
 1:  1   0   0   0   1   0   0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 2:  1   0   0   0   1   0   0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
 3:  1   0   0   0   0   1   0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
 4:  2   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 5:  2   0   0   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 6:  2   0   1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 7:  3   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 8:  3   0   1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 9:  3   0   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
10:  4   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
11:  4   0   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
12:  4   0   0   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
```

### Previous

Here is another approach - this only gets the combination variables so far, but I'll update it when you clarify (see my comment) which product will determine whether or not CP gets replaced from 1 to 0.

```
setDT(Data)

df =  melt(Data[, id:=.I], id="id",measure =patterns("CP", "PR"), value.name = c("CP", "PR"))
result = do.call(cbind, lapply(unique(df$variable), function(i) {
  do.call(cbind, lapply(unique(df$variable), function(j) {
    result = merge(df[variable==i], df[variable==j], by="id")[,`:=`(p=CP.x*PR.y)]
    setnames(result[, .(p)], new=paste0("CP",i,"_PR",j))
  }))
}))
cbind(Data, result)[,id:=NULL][]
```

Output:

````
    ID CP1 CP2 CP3 PR1 PR2 PR3 CP1_PR1 CP1_PR2 CP1_PR3 CP2_PR1 CP2_PR2 CP2_PR3 CP3_PR1 CP3_PR2 CP3_PR3
 1:  1   1   0   0   1   0   0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 2:  1   0   1   0   1   0   0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
 3:  1   0   1   0   0   1   0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
 4:  2   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 5:  2   0   0   0   0   0   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 6:  2   0   1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 7:  3   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 8:  3   0   1   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 9:  3   0   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
10:  4   1   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
11:  4   0   0   0   0   0   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
12:  4   0   0   1   0   0   1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1```
````

Comment: @Didie: which product do you want to use to replace CP values? Look at row 1.   While CP1_PR1 = 1 in row 1 (implying that CP1 should be switched from 1 to 0), CP1_PR2 = 0, which implies that CP1 should NOT be switched from 1 to 0).  Clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want for example in the first row, CP1 to be changed to 0 from the moment than the product with CP1_Pr1 is 1.

Comment: got it..and then subsequent products with CPI will be zero.., so the order of making products is important..